# Using a forEach inside a filter to organize data

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter, foreach

I am trying to filter through a large set of data that has an array nested inside whos values I need to compare against a string. To compare them I need to clean the strings because its coming through user input and spacing/capitalization may vary. So I had my functions working through a filter that looked like this

data initially looked like

```
formularyOptions = [{Condition: "headache"...}{Condition: "hair loss"..}...]
chiefComplaint = "Headache"
```

```
const cleanText = (value) => {
  let str = value;
  if (!str) {
    return value;
  }
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  str = str.replace(/\s/g, "");
  return str;
};

let formularyList = formularyOptions.filter(
      (item) => !!chiefComplaint && cleanText(item.Condition) === cleanText(chiefComplaint),
      
    );
```

And this worked just fine but now

My data looks like this:

```
[{Condition: ["headache", "migraine"]...}{Condition: ["hair loss"]..}...]
```

Ive tried changing my filter to loop through the Conditions array but that doesnt return anything for some reason I dont understand. And the includes method wont work since it is case sensitive. Any advice on how to approach this or even why a forEach wouldnt work inside a .filter would be super helpful this is my attempt with a for loop:

```
let formularyList = formularyOptions.filter(
      (item) => !!chiefComplaint && item.Condition.forEach((condition) => cleanText(condition) === cleanText(chiefComplaint)),
      
    );
```

which just returns an empty array..

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return any value - you seem to be expecting it to return a boolean.

use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) instead

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i don't think .every can work since it tests whether all elements in the array pass the test and some of the arrays will have multiple values inside and I only need one to pass for it to be accepted. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are including a `.forEach(...)` inside a boolean conditional, but it is void, it only loops, nothing is returnted.

I think you actually need to use  the `.some(...)` instead, which will try to find some item that corresponds to the condition:

```
let formularyList = formularyOptions.filter(
      (item) => !!chiefComplaint && item.Condition.some((condition) => cleanText(condition) === cleanText(chiefComplaint)),
      
    );
```